# a set of diameter $d$ is contained in a ball of diameter $d$?

Tags: geometry, analysis

Suppose $S$ is a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $d$ is the diameter of $S$. Is $S$ contained in some ball of radius $d/2$?

Comment: How a triangle could be a counter example? Triangles a connected

Comment: @fan: What course is this for?

Comment: True for $n=1$. False for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @Clayton My head is now in such a mess. Talk to you on Monday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think as you say, a solid equilateral triangle with side lengths $d$ disproves this.  The obvious choice of centre for the ball would be the centroid but the distances to the diagonal are greater than $\frac{d}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what is "diagonal"?

Comment: You probably mean the distance to the vertices.

Comment: If $w$ is the center of the hypothetical $d/2$ radius ball containing the triangle, then conversely $w$ belongs to each $d/2$ radius ball centered at the vertices of the triangle; but the intersection of these balls is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so; let S be the closure of a ball of radius $d/2$ (that is, the closed ball of radius $d/2$). The diameter of this is $d$. The boundary is outside of the ball of radius $d/2$.

Comment: just assume it's a closed ball which he is referring to.  Then the problem becomes interesting

Comment: The OP never said the ball was open...